# Want to import an FXML as a scene, and then use the camera from the FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I want to make 3d objects(using blender) and put them inside of javaFx using the Interactive Mesh:Model Browser. This puts out a FXML with all of the info's I need. I have a camera in that FXMl(that basicly came from blender) and I want it to use that camera as the MAIN camera.

I have tried loading the object from the fxml using lookup and getNamespace.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;


public class main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage stage){
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ground.fxml"));
        Group base = new Group();
        PerspectiveCamera camera;
        Parent root=new Parent(){};
        try {
            root = loader.load();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        base=(Group)root.lookup("#Full3DScene");
        camera= (PerspectiveCamera) base.lookup("#camera");
        Scene scene = new Scene(base,1920,1080);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        scene.setCamera(camera);
        stage.show();
        camera.getId();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!
[This is a view from the camera using InteractiveMesh:ModelBrowserJFX 0.4.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdwiw.png)

FXML Looks Like :

```
<Group fx:id="Full3DScene" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" fx:controller="Controller">
  <transforms>
    <Rotate angle="-90.0" pivotX="0.0" pivotY="0.0" pivotZ="0.0">
      <axis>
        <Point3D x="1.0" y="0.0" z="0.0" />
      </axis>
    </Rotate>
  </transforms>
  <children>
    //...all objects for the scene...
    //+
    <PerspectiveCamera fx:id="camera">
    </PerspectiveCamera>
  </children>
</Group>
```

What I did 
Blender->.dae(Collada)->InteractiveMesh:Model Browser->FXML->javaFx

Comment: There's not enough code here for me to test this (please consider writing a [MCVE] and posting it in the question); but the `FXMLLoader` doesn't even parse the FXML file until you call `load()`, so there's no way the namespace can be populated before `load` is called. So presumably `camera` is `null` here? Try moving the assignment of `camera` to after the point in your code where you call `loader.load()`. As an aside, you really should have all the code from `loader.load()` on inside the `try { .. }` block, because if `load()` fails, none of the rest can work either.

Comment: I've added more code if it clarifies anything.

Comment: CSS lookups are worse; they typically aren't available until the first CSS pass is made, which is after (sometimes not immediately after) the scene has actually been rendered. What actually happens here? Do you get null pointer exceptions? Or just don't get the camera? If you revert to the `namespace.get(...)` but do so after the call to `load()` it should work.

Comment: I tried the code you posted (I removed the `fx:controller`) and it seems to work...? If you're getting null pointer exceptions it may be because the CSS lookup is happening too soon, so try the fix in the comment above. But if not, I'm not sure what the question is: what are you expecting to happen that isn't happening?

Comment: I'm hoping to have the perspective I have in blender or even from the modelviewer. Same as you, I do not have nullExeptions, just that it doesnt put me where I want in the app...

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: Sorry this was just made togheter to test stuff out.